# Socket.IO manually "disconnect" and var scopes for emit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, network-programming

Can someone explain how disconnect works?

In my console logs, the disconnect function is called twice when a client leaves the game. Why is this? When it happens it seems the scope of playerName is also known on the second call but not the first. Is it the same client making those calls? Also, how does it know playerName in that scope, but in `send-message` it doesn't know what playerName is? **(1 is the playerName)**

```
Oct 06 11:57:36 overwatchtracker app/web.1: [RECV] Player disconnected: 1 
Oct 06 11:57:36 overwatchtracker app/web.1: [RECV] Player disconnected: undefined
Oct 06 11:57:29 overwatchtracker app/web.1: [RECV] Message: undefined asdfasdf
```

Here is some of my code:

```
const io = socketIO(server)
var clients = []
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    var playerName;
    socket.on('login-user', (name) => {
        playerName = name
    })
    socket.on('send-message', (message) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('send-message', playerName, message)
    })
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('player-disconnected', playerName)
        for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
            if (clients[i].name == playerName) {
                clients.splice(i, 1)
            }
        }
    })
)}
```

Comment: Show us your client side code.  I would guess that each page is making two connections and one of them never sends `login-user` so when it disconnects, the name is `undefined`.  You can also add a `console.log()` to the `connection` handler to see if there is an extra connection being made.